# how to extract a compiled figure as a standalone pdf file

Tags: floats, pdf, export

I am using Inkscape to include text to pdf figures I create with Illustrator. I would like to know if it is possible to extract the resulting compiled image, together with text, to a standalone pdf file I can use in other documents. I can't use the original pdf file because it has no text.

Comment: I assume you are using inkscapes export as pdf+text option and you want the standalone image with the text rendered by TeX? Did you look at the standalone class?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the file the same way you would in full Latex document. To get a standalone version, use the standalone class.

Here is kind of an example

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85} %if using lualatex, delete this line if using pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
         % you need to set the size of the picture. as standalone, it basically sets the ratio of image to text size (because text size is fixed in pt while image size is variable).
        \def\svgwidth{1\textwidth}
        % this is the inkscape generated Tex code file
        \input{Inkscape_export.pdf_tex}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

If you have trouble with clipped text, this is due to the way Inkscape exports the text. Have a look in the exported tex file. After some code determining lengths you find a picture-environment where text and pdf are included.

Text is normally included with a line like

```
\put(0.27670713,0.51672495){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{your text}}}%
```

The problem is the \smash which makes the width of the text zero. Therefore the standalone package can not "see" the text anymore and clips it. Depending on your text I recommend to replace the complete makebox simply with your text if it is a oneliner or with a parbox of appropriate width for multiline text. 
Like

\put(0.27670713,0.51672495){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}{your text}}%

This may affect the position of the text, so you maybe need to play around a bit with the x and y values (the two numbers after put).

Comment: I'm having an issue though, in one of the figures the text is cut. How do I make the frame larger to make sure all the text fits?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still the figure doesn't include the text around. The line now looks like you suggested: `\put(0.16, 0.33){\color[rgb]{0,0,0} text}`. Something that seemed to work was the command `\phantom`, which made some of the text to the left appear. But the text on top I have no idea.

Comment: Can you post a MWE? It's hard to diagnose this without the actual picture

Comment: You can just post the picture environment and replace the \includegraphics with a corresponding \rule (or let me do the replacement)